# Which are the Data Driven Consensus Algorithms implemented in Blockchain Protocols

Tags: protocols, blockchain, distributed-system, consensus

Consensus Algorithms are found to be either proof of computational work or proof of  economic stake or proof of authority or proof of capacity or a proof of burn or proof of importance or a combination of these approaches or any fault tolerant routing approach. In all these scenarios, consensus routes blocks towards particular nodes based on their roles and responsibilities.

Which are the consensus algorithms where blocks are routed to nodes based on their metadata or data related attributes and properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find following data validation focused Blockchain platforms :

https://dataeum.io/

Dataeum does data collection and analysis in a crowd sourcing approach.

https://dbrain.io/

DBrain is a crowd sourced data validation and image labelling approach.